# Getting an error when using gather to create clustered bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a clustered bar chart and am trying to use the gather function to get the correct bars to group together. When I do this, I get the error that the gather function could not be found. I have dplyr and magrittr installed. Any thoughts on how to make this work or if there is a better way to create the bar chart grouped by test and date?

```
Plaster <- Plaster_2019_Data %>%
  gather("pH", "Temperature", "Surface", -Date)
```

Data:

```
Surface pH  Temperature Date    
12.08   8.56    11.16   5/13/2019   
11.68   8.90    8.76    5/29/2019   
8.69    9.07    14.65   6/10/2019   
2.26    7.49    17.51   6/24/2019   
4.54    7.77    23.82   7/8/2019    
2.13    8.17    25.29   8/5/2019    
6.34    8.62    26.50   8/19/2019   
9.33    9.03    24.31   9/4/2019    
10.98   8.58    21.02   9/16/2019   
9.59    8.61    17.33   9/30/2019   
16.07   8.70    10.39   10/14/2019  
9.12    8.07    6.38    11/14/2019
```

Comment: You need `install.packages('tidyr')` or call `require('tidyr')`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `require` to install and load the package `tidyr` as `gather` is from `tidyr`

```
require('tidyr')
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @akrun, you need `tidyr`. Moreover, the function `pivot_longer` is dedicated to replace in a near future the function `gather` (https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html).

Moreover, as the range of values between your test is quite different, I would suggest to use `facet_wrap` to make a nice plot.

Altogether, you can write something like that:

```r
df$Date = as.Date(df$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df %>% pivot_longer(., -Date, names_to = "Test", values_to = "value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = value, fill = Test))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge())+
  facet_wrap(.~Test, scales = "free") +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %d",
               date_breaks = "2 weeks")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

**Data**

```r
structure(list(Surface = c(12.08, 11.68, 8.69, 2.26, 4.54, 2.13, 
6.34, 9.33, 10.98, 9.59, 16.07, 9.12), pH = c(8.56, 8.9, 9.07, 
7.49, 7.77, 8.17, 8.62, 9.03, 8.58, 8.61, 8.7, 8.07), Temperature = c(11.16, 
8.76, 14.65, 17.51, 23.82, 25.29, 26.5, 24.31, 21.02, 17.33, 
10.39, 6.38), Date = structure(c(18029, 18045, 18057, 18071, 
18085, 18113, 18127, 18143, 18155, 18169, 18183, 18214), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
```